# What is the best DLL-Base Database for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, database, hosting

I have a Hosting which doesn't support `SQL server` or any other databse because it is cheap. I know that there are some Dll in which we can add to project and use it as the database.

I wantto know that which one is the best? and is there any other solution to use a database in a Hosting which doesn't support any kind of Database? (don't tell that you can usefile-base database, cause I don't like it)

Comment: Aren't all databases file-based under the hood anyway?

Comment: Presuming they mean not service based.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes they are but in behind the sence,You know I'd rader Dll databses

Comment: Keep in mind that generally sqlite will not work in medium trust environment, and most shared hosting give you only medium trust.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx), or [SqlLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) with a .NET provider (like this one: [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)).

Answer (score 7):

Best might be subjective, but
[Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2) or [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

SQL Server Compact Edition 4 was updated to enable:

- Enabled to work in the medium or partial trust environments in the web servers, and can be easily deployed along with the website to the third party website hosting service providers.

Answer (score 5):

FireBird is also a good choice.
Read more about it.

[What is a good embedded database to use with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c/3661124#3661124)

Answer (score 2):

There is an sql server [compact editon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you have no access to a data base server.  Also if you host doesn't support databases you can get hosted databases from another provider.  Another very popular DBMSless option is [Sql light](http://www.sqlite.org/) which I have used in c and am sure some one has extended to use in c#.

Answer (score 2):

I would take **SQLite** over SQL Compact Edition in notime.

So, for small apps, I always go with SQLite.

You have a good (maybe the best) library for C# [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) as well, you can use a small app to view the database using [SQLite Admin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)

It **might** interest you:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583278/sqlite-vs-sqlce-vs-in-a-mobile-application

and

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278104/sql-ce-sqlite-what-are-the-differences-between-them

Comment: The negative of that: no upward scaling way. Sql Compact you can easily upgrade to use a real server should the need arise.

Comment: you can easily use Entity Framework to move stuff from one place to another

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you Db4o (Database for objects): http://www.db4o.com

It's an object-oriented database and it works like a charm since it store objects instead of tables and rows, that may be a good choice for you as it'll free you of creating a data access layer, object-relational mapping and so.

Anyway, I'll tell you that if you're going to host data for some multi-user application, any of possible solutions would be a bad choice because you'll have great performance issues.

Comment: "any of possible solutions would be a bad choice because you'll have great performance issues." - care to elborate?

Comment: "[...] because these are stored in a single file and each thread needs an exclusive lock over the file in order to read and write data [...]" (or, depending on database technology, at least, to write the file).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `SqlLite` and happy with it. It works greatly even in cheapest shared web hostings.